# Logic for creating graph c++

Tags: c++, graph

I am working on a project where I am given a list of edges with a weight of either A or B. I need eventually determine if it is possible to create a spanning tree with 'x' number of A edges.

Right now I am trying to make a list of all the edges that are used in creating the minimally spanning tree and am doing that by making a list of the vertices that I have used. If two of the vertices have been used then that edges is discarded. The problem I am having is that once I get to the end my graph, I am often left with two halves of graphs that are not connected because the edge that would connect the two halves have already been used. Any thoughts on how I can fix this problem, or is the overall approach wrong?

```
struct Edge{
    int start;
    int end;
    char letter;
    bool used;

};

void PrimWhite(...)
{
vector<int> usedVertices;
int count,maxNum,begin,end;

int totalVertexs = 0;
maxNum = whiteEdge.size();

Edge temp;
Edge *point = &temp;
Edge *usedorNah;

for (count = 0;count < maxNum; count++)
{
    temp = whiteEdge[count];
    usedorNah = &whiteEdge[count];
    begin = point->start;
    end = point->end;

    if ( (find(usedVertices.begin(), usedVertices.end(), begin) == usedVertices.end()) && (find(usedVertices.begin(), usedVertices.end(), end) == usedVertices.end()))
    {
        usedVertices.push_back(begin);
        usedVertices.push_back(end);
        totalVertexs = totalVertexs + 2; 
        usedorNah->used = true;
    }
    else if ((find(usedVertices.begin(), usedVertices.end(), begin) == usedVertices.end()) && (find(usedVertices.begin(), usedVertices.end(), end) != usedVertices.end()))
    {
        usedVertices.push_back(begin);
        totalVertexs++;
        usedorNah->used = true;
    }
    else if ((find(usedVertices.begin(), usedVertices.end(), begin) != usedVertices.end()) && (find(usedVertices.begin(), usedVertices.end(), end) == usedVertices.end()) )
    {
        usedVertices.push_back(end);
        totalVertexs++;
        usedorNah->used = true;
    }
```

[image: Example of the issues, the two halves are not connected]

[image: Full Graph]

Answer (score 1):

Just use the criterion that Kruskal's algorithm uses: Add an edge to the graph if it does not form a loop. To check this, you have to check if the two incident nodes are connected to the same connected component. This can be done efficiently with the Union-Find data structure. I.e. whenever you add an edge, unite the components of both vertices. Before adding an edge, check if the two components are the same.